# Advantages of a guillotine over a bookbinder's plough?

Tags: cutting, book-binding, paper-cutter

What can a guillotine (AKA paper cutter) do that a bookbinder's plough can't, if anything?

Comment: Do you have more specific products in mind? Individual products are likely to differ in things like the thickness they can cut, and "guillotine" can refer to a wide range of things, with hinged or rotary blades. It seems quite common to have ploughs attached to book presses, while guillotines are generally separate.